# Como pegar o resultado de outro método em Java?

Tags: java, android-studio

Como eu pego o resultado do método 2 e coloco junto com `Resultado.setText` do método 1?

- 1

```
public void CalcularIMC(View view) {

        //recuperar valores digitados
        String Didade = editeIdade.getText().toString();
        String Daltura = editeAltura.getText().toString();
        String Dpeso = editePeso.getText().toString();

        //Convertendo string para números
        int    idade = Integer.parseInt(Didade);
        double altura = Double.parseDouble(Daltura);
        double peso = Double.parseDouble(Dpeso);

        // variaveis
        double ideal = altura * altura;
        double resultado = peso / ideal;


        //ARREDONDAR E DIMINUIR O NÚMERO DE CASAS DECIMAIS EM JAVA
        DecimalFormat formatador = new DecimalFormat("00.00");

        if (resultado <= 18.5) {
            Resultado.setText("Idade : " + idade +  "\nSeu IMC é: " + formatador.format(resultado) +
                    "\nMagreza: \nQuando o resultado é menor que 18,5 kg/m2");
        }
        if (resultado >= 18.5 || resultado <= 24.9) {
            Resultado.setText("Idade : " + idade + "\nSeu IMC é: " + formatador.format(resultado) +
                    "\nNormal: \nQuando o resultado está entre 18,5 e 24,9 kg/m2");
        }
        if (resultado >= 24.9 || resultado <= 30) {
            Resultado.setText("Idade : " + idade + "\nSeu IMC é: " + formatador.format(resultado) +
                    "\nSobrepeso: \nQuando o resultado está entre 24,9 e 30 kg/m2");
        }
        if (resultado >= 30) {
            Resultado.setText("Idade : " + idade + "\n Seu IMC é: " + formatador.format(resultado) +
                    "\n Obesidade: \nQuando o resultado é maior que 30 kg/m2");
        }

    }
```

- 2

```
public void radiobutton(){
                    genero.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int checkedId) {
                            if (checkedId == R.id.radioButtonM){
                                Resultado.setText("Masculino");
                            }else if (checkedId == R.id.radioButtonF){
                                Resultado.setText("Feminino");
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
```

Comment: O que você quer dizer com "resultado do método 2"? Colocar o que exatamente no método 1?

Comment: Preciso colocar o  Resultado.setText("Masculino"); para aparecer junto com Resultado.setText("Idade : " + idade +  "\nSeu IMC é: " + formatador.format(resultado) +
                    "\nMagreza: \nQuando o resultado é menor que 18,5 kg/m2");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagino que a variável `Resultado` seja um input. Como você está dando um setText(String), no método 1 você consegue dar um getText() e concatenar, exemplo:

```
if (resultado <= 18.5) {
            Resultado.setText(resultado.getText() + "\n" + "Idade : " + idade +  "\nSeu IMC é: " + formatador.format(resultado) +
                    "\nMagreza: \nQuando o resultado é menor que 18,5 kg/m2");
        }
```

Uma sugestão, use a classe [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) para dar um setText no resultado, exemplo:

```
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
        text.append(Resultado.getText() + "\n");

        if (resultado <= 18.5) {
            text.append(("Idade : " + idade +  "\nSeu IMC é: " + formatador.format(resultado) +
                    "\nMagreza: \nQuando o resultado é menor que 18,5 kg/m2");
        }
        if (resultado >= 18.5 || resultado <= 24.9) {
            text.append("Idade : " + idade + "\nSeu IMC é: " + formatador.format(resultado) +
                    "\nNormal: \nQuando o resultado está entre 18,5 e 24,9 kg/m2");
        }
        Resultado.setText(text.toString());
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado! você me salvou.